# Can't paste image files into applications

Tags: windows-10, copy-paste

I can not paste any image files into applications like photoshop, paint or paint.net.
If I copy an image from a browser it works fine.
Copying an image file into a folder works.

Comment: https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-elements/why-is-my-copy-and-paste-not-working/m-p/8524623?profile.language=pt

Comment: @ChanganAuto I don't think you understood my problem. It is not only photoshop, it is every application. I rightclick a file on desktop and can't paste it anywhere except other folders.